# How to create discrete high voltage oscillator?

Tags: voltage, clock, switching, multiplier

I need to increase 24 V DC to 1.5 kV DC. Using a voltage multiplier would require over 60 stages.

I am considering using a few stages of a voltage multiplier, say 8, to increase the voltage to about 100 V. Then, take this 100 V as an input to a independent voltage multiplier, so 8 stages increase this value to 400 V (instead of 200 V if these stages were just added to the previous 8). Repeating this step would result in a output voltage of 1600 V.

The problem I am having with this is finding a way to oscillate the 100 V and 400 V inputs. I have not found any ICs able to switch just a high voltage, I suspect I may have to do this with discrete components.

How may I build the switching device?

Additional note: The switching will be between 0 V and the input voltage (no negatives)   ***unless using an inverter to create a complimentary negative voltage would be useful?[image: Four stage multiplier. (Vout = 2xVin when no negative input.]

Comment: It sounds like you're wilfully trying to do this the hard way, an intermediate DC stage is nonsense. Use a push-pull pair of FETs to drive a ferrite transformer from 24v, stepping up to a few hundred volts AC. Rectify the output in a few stages of multiplier.

Comment: Thanks, I will explore that option. Still, increasing to 200 V with a transformer, how could I then switch this voltage to reach the 1600 V needed? (I would like to use small and cheap components, a multiplier allows for lower voltage ratings as none are connected to ground except for the input)

Comment: @A.S. I'll repeat an important part that Neil just said. "*an intermediate DC stage is nonsense*".

Comment: You could try a 2 stage topology like they use in Taser guns. Use a transformer to boost the voltage to 300 VDC. Another transformer to boost 300 volts to 1,600. This is more efficient than one transformer with a thousand secondary winding's.

Comment: @Sparky256 the reason I am leaning toward a voltage multiplier, especially for the latter higher voltage part of the circuit, is because I cannot find flyback transformers in stock which can handle that voltage. Would a regular transformer work in this case?

Comment: Have fun at [DIY Physics](http://www.diyphysics.com/category/instrumentation/high-voltage-power-supply/).

Comment: That is the crux of the issue. Diodes can only do so much, but winding transformers is a   very tedious task. No easy way out of this one

Comment: [10 kV from a 3 volt battery answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66072/charging-a-circuit-to-around-10kv-from-3v-two-aa-batteries-for-discharge-over)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2XMNL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

... with appropriate drive timing, gate resistors, power supply decoupling, right frequency for the core area, the usual stuff between back-of-envelope and a working circuit.