# Boost converter to high voltages (20 kV+)

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, high-voltage

I am interested in making a mini, potentially portable ion thruster.

**The Question:** Is it possible to create a boost converter that takes low voltage batteries ranging from 3.7 V to 24 V and boost that to 20 kV or higher which is continuous voltage (not pulsed)?

**The Reason:** So far I have used an old 20 kV AC DC power supply to make a ion thruster, but now I would like one that doesn't necessarily have to be plugged into the wall.

I have looked online and have seen high voltage inverters, the problem is that they are too low in voltage output to be effective (and AC), or they have high voltage output but its pulsed - and I would like a continuous flow.

Thanks and I look forward to hearing your comments!

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll need to draw a lot of current from your batteries to get a little current out of the output. I imagine you probably know that, but it's important to keep in mind when selecting batteries!

Comment: Start [here](http://www.diyphysics.com/category/instrumentation/high-voltage-power-supply/). They have written a book, too.

Comment: [6 kV boost circuit from 3 volt battery could be used as basis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66072/charging-a-circuit-to-around-10kv-from-3v-two-aa-batteries-for-discharge-over). Add more voltage doublers to get more output or use higher turns ratio in transformer. I used this type of circuit to generate 55 kV (very carefully) once.

Comment: Not so long ago televisions and oscilloscopes needed tens of kilovolts DC with substantial current to generate fast  enough electron beam with the needed amount of electrons in the cathode ray tube. Try to check their circuits. If you are lucky you can find a  TV to cannibalize.  At least the transformer is difficult to make. As others already hinted: To get 1 mA at 20kV you need 1A at 20V or 2A at 10V as a theoretical minimum, in practice prepare to feed say 30% more due all kind of losses.

Comment: @jonk there was a Febetron where I worked. It was on the 3rd floor and pointed out the window. You had to make sure that the window cleaner used a brush on a long stick and that they didn't climb a ladder.

Comment: It's important that your first stage be as efficient as possible, because each stage takes its toll on efficiency.  For instance, three 72% efficiency stages gives you a 37.3% final efficiency. If you're going to let go of the international space station and be at Mars anytime soon, you better do your math right! ;-} So synchronous and/or resonant might be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use your boost converter into a diode pump.

You will want many stages, but the individual voltages are more manageable like say 40 stages at 500 VDC each. This means fast diodes, capacitors, and boost MOSFET that see only 500 VDC.

This is my preferred way to make high DC voltages at low currents.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I will look into this.