# DC-DC converter with 0.5-2kV output

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter

I want to buy a DC-DC converter which can convert 1.5-12V (input) to 0.5kV to 2kV (output). I searched the internet for such a converter but couldn't find one. I think such a converter exists as they are used in camera flash diffusers to convert 1.5V from the battery to 1kV in order to power the xenon flash tube.
If you want to know why I need such a converter- I'm interested in building a parallel plate electrostatic generator that requires input voltages of thousands of Volts. So I want to convert 5 or 12V from a battery to 1.5kV with the help of the converter and supply the 1.5kV to the parallel plates.
Now my question is do such converters exist? If yes do they have a specific name?
I don't want the converter to be too big I.e. its all three dimensions should be less than 150mm.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66072/charging-a-circuit-to-around-10kv-from-3v-two-aa-batteries-for-discharge-over)

Comment: Be precise in how you write what you want! "0.5-2kV (output)" is that 0.5 V to 2 kV or is that 0.5 kV to 2 kV? Does the output need to be adjustable? A camera flash circuit is much simpler, usually 3 V to 1.5 kV. Note how I do not specify a range as that confuses things.